# 403 - Forbidden on basic MVC 3 deploy on iis7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

I am trying to deploy a basic MVC 3 application to my 2008 R2 Server running iis 7.5 but receive a "403 - Forbidden" error trying to view my page.

I have anonymous authentication enabled, and my app pool is using the "ApplicationPoolIdentity" in integrated pipeline mode with .net 4.0.  I don't know what "user" the "ApplicationPoolIdentity" is, but I've given IUSR read/write rights to the website folder.

I don't have any other authentication schemes in place, the server is not even running in a domain.

If I put a default html page in there, it loads fine.  It's only my methods/controllers that I cannot get to function.

How else can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks,

Comment: see this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Run `aspnet_regiis -i`.   Often I've found you need to do that to get 4.0 apps to work.  Open a command prompt:

```
cd \
cd Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework\v4.xxx.xxx
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Once it has installed and registered, make sure you application is using an application pool that is set to .NET 4.0.

Comment: I just found a potential issue with this command.  Using -i updated all web applications (pools) to ASP.NET 4.0.  

Using `aspnet_regiis -ir` installs the version of ASP.NET but does not change any web applications to this version.  You may also want to review the -iru option.

Comment: Use `aspnet_regiis -iru` to avoid affecting any existing web apps!

Comment: @Michael Shimmins, don't know how to thanks you, spend half day figuring this out, finally worked, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Micheal for the help.

My OS is 64bit, so I ran aspnet_regiis.exe in Framework64 which solved the problem.

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>
```

This was after running aspnet_regiis in folder ...\Framework\v4.0.30319 which did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to try:

1. Give permission to the directory in which your website is stored to "Network Services".  That's the account that is used for ApplicationPoolIdentity [in Server 2008.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28WS.10%29.aspx)
2. If that fails, change ApplicationPoolIdentity to an account for which you have given explicit permissions to your website directory.