# Not able to route to a view under area in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to route to a Login view under Area(Test Area) not working.

**Exception:**

*HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory*

**Most likely causes:**
*A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.*

If I route to view other than the login view under area it works fine

What I'm doing wrong in routing??

**Area:**

**Test Area Registartion.cs**

```
public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Test";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Test_default",
                "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Roue Config in App_Start :**

*If I use default route for login it works fine ,but if I give route to login view under test area it gives HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this director why??*

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            // Default Route for Login
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            //Area View Route for Login
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication1.Areas.Test.Controllers" }
            );

        }
    }
```

**Global.asax.cs :**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer<WebApplication1.Areas.Test.Models.Test_DB>(null);
    }
```

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323190/http-error-403-14-forbidden-iis-error-for-asp-net-mvc-4-application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this:**

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication1.Areas.Test.Controllers" }).DataTokens["area"] = "Test";
```