# MVC 5 application on IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I have an `MVC 5` application and when I browse to it through `IIS`(version 8), I get a `403.14`  with the message The web server is configured to not list contents of this directory.  Its like the routing is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you're seeing that `403.14` error code because IIS failed to navigate the project resources. If your routing was the problem, you will see `404`.

There are two things you need to check out for your error.

1. **Make sure your IIS can access to your web project.**

For IIS to access your resources, you need to give Read/Write permission to your IIS.

- Right click on the project folder you're trying to deploy
- Select `Security` tab
- Check if there is an `IUSR` account listed up on the user ( or group ) panel
- If there isn't, Add `IUSR` and give Read/Write permission ( by default, it has already ).

---

2. **Make sure the deploy directory was set up correctly in IIS**

MVC directory can be tricky for a user with less experience. You can easily get confused by which directories should be the destination folder for IIS. It must be the parent folder of `Web.config`. Please doublecheck you set your project folder right.

This will resolve that error. If another HTML error code comes out, then it is safe to think that you completed a first step for `.NET MVC` deployment on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

403.14 means that you do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. 
make sure that your virtual directory was created correctly and IIS has access to read/write on it.
You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323190/http-error-403-14-forbidden-iis-error-for-asp-net-mvc-4-application) and [here](http://sanuja.com/blog/resolving-iis-403-forbidden-access-is-denied)